# QTime->addSecs cause segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing simple *pomodoro* application, which is basically countdown timer. Right now, I've got countdown working, but the weird thing is that when I add another attribute to my class (arbitrary), I get **Sedmentation fault** error.

Using gdb, the problem should be here:

```
void Status::showPomodoroTime() {
    QTime time = pomodoroTime->addSecs(elapsed);
    activeTime->display(time.toString("mm:ss"));
}
```

where activeTime is QLCDNumber widget and elapsed is int.

More context:

```
void Status::createDefaultIntervals()
{
    pomodoroInterval = new QTime(0, 25);
    pomodoroBreak = new QTime(0, 5);
    pomodoroLongBreak = new QTime(0, 15);
}

void Status::run()
{
    if (pomodoroActive == STOP) {
        pomodoroTime = pomodoroInterval;
        showPomodoroTime();
    }
    pomodoroActive = RUN;
    updateStatusArea();
    timerTick();
}
```

CreateDefaultInterval definitely runs before showPomodoroTime.

What bugs me, that whole application works fine. Just when I add another attribute, it starts to throw sedfault.

**How can variable declaration in *.h file cause segfault in *.cpp?**

If you want more code, I can put it anywhere. I just don't know, what place is persistent enough. Don't want to post it here (about 300 lines of code).

Comment: check if `pomodoroTime` is a valid pointer

Comment: Is `Status` copyable? If so, are copy constructor and assignment operator implemented?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: Well, I guess so. It points to the same value as pomodoroInterval, which points to valid QTime object.

Comment: @elvard, if you have not explicity declared the copy constructor and assignment operator as `private` then `Status` is copyable. If you have not implemented them then the default versions of these two functions will be used which is incorrect if the class, as `Status` appears to have, has dynamically allocated member variables.

Comment: Just to make sure: you are _rebuilding_ each time you add a member variable, not just doing a 'normal' build?

Comment: There's usually no good reason to create QTime object's on the heap. Better put them on the stack.

Comment: @cmannett85, I dunno, I just run `make` and it compiles whatever it needs… Usually with changed header file, it compile whole application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if(pomodoro!= NULL) and then do addSecs().

Comment: That does not guarantee that `pomodoro` points to a valid object.

Comment: Checking for NULL isn't enough

Comment: Well, yes, that's the solution. Question is, why it worked before I altered header file? I've just added not relevant attribute… Another int.

Comment: yes you guys are right that only checking against NULL is not enough. I was  assuming that pomodoro is either initialized to NULL (in constructor or during declaration within the function or new'd)

Answer (score 0):

pomodoroTime is probably uninitialized or deleted